# How do "three way data binding" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, angularjs, binding, angularfire

How do binding(angularjs) a database(mysql) with my view? 
Is there any framework similar to angularfire for MySQL?
"three way data binding"

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on your application server, the database here really doesn't have anything to do it with it but rather how you retrieve and write to the database.

What you really need to achieve a "three way data binding" is server push technology which can be accomplished using web sockets.

For php, which is a popular choice with mysql look at [ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

If you're not using php, just search for a web socket technology related to your application server technology.